# Nameless void pointer as parameter?

Tags: c++, pointers, parameters

This is the signature of a function in VirtualBox:

```
static DECLCALLBACK(void) svcCall (void *,
                                   VBOXHGCMCALLHANDLE callHandle,
                                   uint32_t u32ClientID,
                                   void *pvClient,
                                   uint32_t u32Function,
                                   uint32_t cParms,
                                   VBOXHGCMSVCPARM paParms[])
```

I don't know what the first parameter, `void *` is supposed to mean and how one would work with it.

What is its use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably not used in that implementation. Leaving it without a name avoids the compiler warning

> ```
> unused parameter xyz
> ```

To know what this parameter means you should have a look at the callback functions declaration, rather than an arbitrary implementation.

Comment: I didn't think of that possibility. I actually found other examples of that function, where the first parameter is a `void *pvService`. No idea what that means right now, but at least I now have an answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> what the first parameter, void * is supposed to mean

It means that the first parameter is of type `void*`. Not giving the parameter a name implies that the parameter is unused on purpose.

> how one would work with it

One doesn't, becase one can't *work with it*.

> What is its use?

If you want a definitive answer, you should ask the VirtualBox developer that wrote it. I'm not them, but I can give you a guess:

Perhaps, the function is used as a callback. And the callback is specified to have a void pointer as the first parameter. But this particular callback does not need the value of the void pointer.